# how to insert values into mysql table from another bigquery response

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql, google-api-python-client

My Python program connects to BigQuery and fetching data which I want to insert into a MySQL table.  It's successfully fetching the results from BigQuery.  It's also successfully connecting to MySQL DB but it's not inserting the data.  I see its complaining for the `row[1]`.

What's the right way to insert the values from BigQuery response into MySQL table columns?

```python
query_data = {mybigquery}

query_response = query_request.query(projectId='myprojectid',body=query_data).execute()

for row in query_response['rows']:
  cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO database.table VALUES ('row[0]','row[1]','row[2]','row[3]','row[4]');")
```

Also, I tried to use

```python
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);")
```

or

```python
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]);")
```

But in all it fails while inserting values in mysql table

Answer (score 1):

### String literals

Regarding the original question, the issue lies with quoting your variables.  This causes the `execute` function to treat them as string literals rather than getting the values from them.

As suggested by @Herman, to properly execute the SQL statement with the values I think you intend, you would need something more like this:

```python
query_data = {mybigquery}
statement = 'INSERT INTO database.table VALUE (%s, %s, %s);'

response = query_request.query(projectId='myprojectid', body=query_data).execute()
rows = response['rows']
for row in rows:
  values = (row[0], row[1], row[2])
  cursor.execute(statement, values)
```

---

### BigQuery query JSON

Keep in mind however that the above will not work out of the box as `row` in the code above does not conform to the response received from the [BigQuery Job: query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#response) API.

In this API, `rows` is an array of `row` objects.  Each `row` object has a property `f` which is an array of fields.  Lastly, each `field` has a property `v` which is the value of this field.

To get the value of second field in a row, you should use `row['f'][1]['v']`.  Since you require a `tuple` or `list` for the `params` argument of the [`cursor.execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) method, you could get a list of field values using list comprehension as follows:

```python
for row in rows:
  values = [field['v'] for field in row['f]]
```

---

### Sanitize values before inserting

The [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) you get once correctly reading the field values may be raised because `execute` or `str` cannot convert a value to a string properly.  One of the significant differences between BigQuery and MySQL is that a value in BigQuery can be a [record](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) with multiple values of its own.  To ensure this gets inserted properly, you must sanitize those values yourself prior to inserting them.  If the value is a `list` or `dict`, it cannot be stored in MySQL without being serialized in some way like with the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) method.

---

### Example

```python
def sanitize(value):
  if type(value) is list:
    return str(value)
  if type(value) is dict:
    return str(value)
  # this may be required for other types
  return value

data = {mybigquery}
statement = 'INSERT INTO database.table VALUE (%s, %s, %s);'

response = request.query(projectId='projid', body=data).execute()
for row in response['rows']:
  values = [sanitize(field['v']) for field in row['f']]
  cursor.execute(statement, values)
```

This is very basic sanitation.  You should really validate all field values and ensure that they will be properly converted to MySQL types and not simply insert an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message? It should be something like:

cursor.execute(
"INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row[0:5])

Comment: Getting this error  [root@myserver ~]# python myprogram.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myprogram.py", line 25, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row[0:5])
TypeError: unhashable type
[root@myserver ~]#

Comment: I see. Look like you need to str all of the values because the driver does not do it for you.

cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [str(r) for r in row[0:5]])

Comment: Still getting the same error...
Basically, when I use print('\t'.join(field['v'] for field in row['f']))
its printing the values fine... output 
15658   53.35023630093262       221.0   237.0   436.0
But when I try to insert the same data into MySQL DB using 
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "secretpwd", db = "database")
cursor = connection.cursor ()
for row in query_response['rows']:
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",[str(r) for r in row[0:5]])
TypeError: unhashable type